# Find the indices of occurence of an ordered array in a vector - Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

I have two arrays `a = [1,-1,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,0];b = [1,-1];`

I want to find the occurrence of b in a(not any of the values of b in a).
I want 1 followed by -1 occurrence indices in a.

The expected output will be [1,5,7].

I have tried with `ismember` and `find` functions in Matlab. 
Did not get the result I want.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: looks like a `conv` solution to me...

Comment: @Divakar updated the question for expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strfind does exactly what you want: `strfind(a,b)`
Documentation does not mention, but you can use it with doubles as well as with chars.

Comment: Superb answer @Daniel. You can write an article on 'undocumented matlab'.

Answer (score 3):

here's one way:

```
 find(conv(a,b,'same')==-2)
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this could fail if other numbers (aside from -1, 0 and 1) are allowed in vector `a`

Comment: yep, I guess you just did... I was just answering the question exactly, no generalizations.